# Add marker count to GMap by location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking to add a marker count for each location on my map. You'll notice that each of the three places shown on the map has a different number of markers:

[Here's my jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/JimmyRivvers/hwdfgmdk/)

And here's the code if you can eyeball it:

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [
        [40.82829, -73.9271, 'Marker 1'],
        [40.756421, -73.845897, 'Marker 2'],
        [40.756421, -73.845897, 'Marker 3'],
        [40.750704, -73.993752, 'Marker 4'],
        [40.750704, -73.993752, 'Marker 5'],
        [40.750704, -73.993752, 'Marker 6']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.773522, -73.944039),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create markers on the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]); 

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][2]
        });
    }
}

initialize();
```

I'd like to display the count in a div below each marker.

Comment: Have you considered the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, geocodezip. Unfortunately, MarkerClusterer doesn't provide the functionality I need. I'm not looking to group markers, nor am I looking to change the amount of markers that appear as I change zoom level. I'm simply looking to display the number of markers I have for each coordinate.